# splitting string as per regex in typescript is not working as expected for multiple space

Tags: javascript, typescript, split

In typescript I want to divide a name as per space. So, I used something like this

```
const splitted = name.split(' ');
```

It is working as expected, but if wrongly someone gave more than one space. So, i tried to handle multiple space to split. Like this,

```
const splitted = name.split('\\s+');
```

But, it is taking the whole string as 1 And, length of splitted varabel it is showing 1

It is working in java

Any explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `split` along a regular expression, you need to pass an actual regular expression to `split`:

```
const splitted = name.split(/\s+/);
```

Your current code will split along a *literal* backslash, followed by a literal `s` and `+`, eg:

```
const name = 'foo\\s+bar';
const splitted = name.split('\\s+');
// splitted: ['foo', 'bar'];
```

Comment: why the forward slash at the end?

Comment: Just like quotes `'` and `"` are string delimiters, forward slashes are regex delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use backslash no quote when usign Regex:

```
const splitted = name.split(/\s+/g);
```

Comment: why the forward slash at the end?